# Installing BeautifulSoup on Pycharm

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, installation, pycharm

I am trying to install BeautifulSoup and this is the problem

> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in
> C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-n8bpi4nt\BeautifulSoup\

This is the error I receive when I attempt to install BeautifulSoup

This is the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
 
search = input("Enter search term:")
params = {"q": search}
r = requests.get("https://www.bing.com/search", params=paramas)
 
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)  # the text of the document passed into the class beautiful soup
print(soup.prettify())
```

This is the error:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'
```

Comment: how did you try to install it? what code did you use for the installation?

Comment: Are you installing it this way ? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html

Comment: I tried installing from the terminal at first, then tried the method via the 'project interpreter' in the settings. Both of which did not work

Comment: "command error exit status 1", is what i am getting. "Try to run this command from the system terminal. Make sure that you use the correct version of 'pip' installed for your Python interpreter located at 'C:\Users\PC\PycharmProjects\webscraper\venv\Scripts\python.exe'."

Comment: Pip3 install BeautifulSoup

Comment: In python 3 you need to install beautifulsoup4: `pip3 install beautifulsoup4` or if you are using windows `pip install beautifulsoup4`

Comment: Just tried it and it worked. Thank you! I'm a newbie to programming

Comment: @iqram could you accept my proposed answer as correct answer if it solved your problem?

Answer (score 1):

In python 3 you need to install beautifulsoup4 (for mac/ubuntu): `pip3 install beautifulsoup4` or (windows) `pip install beautifulsoup4`

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the BeautifulSoup library on your machine.

Install it as follows:

```
pip install --user --no-cache-dir bs4 lxml # for python 2
```

or,

```
pip3 install --user --no-cache-dir bs4 lxml # for python 3
```

Installing modules for a user is a best practice to avoid global site-packages pollution